# How does one echo a php list item within an ordered list?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am using the repeater field of wordpress' advance custom fields. I have an ordered list. The list items are generated using the repeater field. This is how the static html looks:

```
<ol class="instructions">
    <li>Hallways and transitional spaces are best...</li>
    <li>It is best to keep expensive furnishings such...</li>
    <li>If you want furnishings and accessories to be a bold source...</li>
    <li>Neutral furnishings and accessories? You can afford...</li>
 </ol>
```

The list items have styled numbers beside them.

I am struggling to put the ol together with php as I am very new to learning this language. This is what I have done so far.

```
<?php
    // Check rows exists.
    if(have_rows('rules')):

        // Loop through rows.
        while(have_rows('rules')) : the_row();

        // Load sub field value.
        $rule = get_sub_field('rule');

        // Do something...
        
        echo '<li>' . $rule . '</li>';


        // End loop.
        endwhile;

    // No value.
    else :
        // Do something...
    endif;
?>
```

How do I echo the php li(s) within the ol and give the ol a class of instructions within my php code?

Thank you for any answers. Very grateful <3

Answer (score 1):

Say you have an array of rules;

```
  $rules = [
    "Hallways and transitional spaces are best...",
    "It is best to keep expensive furnishings such...",
    "If you want furnishings and accessories to be a bold source...",
    "Neutral furnishings and accessories? You can afford...",
    ];

    <ol class="instructions">

    <?php
    if(count($rules) > 0):
        foreach($ruels as $rule) {
            echo '<li>' . $rule . '</li>';
        }
    else
        echo '<li> No Instruction Found </li>'
    ?>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `echo '<ol class="instructions">';` before while cycle and `echo '</ol>';` after.

```
<?php
    // Check rows exists.
    if(have_rows('rules')):

        echo '<ol class="instructions">';

        // Loop through rows.
        while(have_rows('rules')) : the_row();

        // Load sub field value.
        $rule = get_sub_field('rule');

        // Do something...
        
        echo '<li>' . $rule . '</li>';


        // End loop.
        endwhile;

        echo '</ol>';

    // No value.
    else :
        // Do something...
    endif;
?>
```